# Unable to connect to worker node using ssh in google cloud

Tags: ssh

I am using ssh command to connect to one of the nodes in cluster from master node (google cloud shell)

```
$ kubectl get nodes

$ kubectl describe node gke-hello-server-default-pool-03b44665-ng8w
```

I selected the external IP and then tried using

```
ssh 35.247.97.140
Permission denied (publickey).
```

again below

```
where nodename is 
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hostname@35.247.97.140
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But in both case I am getting permission  denied.

Comment: what is `hostname`? what's username do you use to ssh?

Comment: I think you have to go in using their web console.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be using

`gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME]`

to connect to an Linux instance.

There is a documentation available on cloud about [Connecting to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).

And if for some reasons that will not work you should navigate to `GCP > Compute Engine > VM instances`, choose the instance you wish to connect and click on **`ssh`** button.

This will connect you on your home user.

So you can add a new user to the system and generate ssh-key for it.
Here is a documentation about [Managing SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).